# can't upload files from computer in any wysiwyg editor

Tags: 6, wysiwyg

When I want to upload an image from an editor it only allows me to insert a URL and the ability to browse and upload a file is missing. 
So there's something that behind all the wysiwyg editor that is preventing me from doing this and honestly don't know where to start looking for this.

Tried FCKeditor, CKeditor, jwysywig and TinyMCE and in all those cases I can only insert a URL but not upload from hard drive

There's a tutorial I found on youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUVPCqUwsdk). At 0:19 you'll see 4 tabs called 'Image Info', 'Links', 'Upload' and 'Advanced' respectively. 
So my problem is the 'Upload' tab is missing from my editor as well as all other editor where this upload function is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) project provides upload capabilities to a variety of WYSIWYG editors. Check the project page for the appropriate way to install it for your particular editor.

Comment: It works. With you, does it enable you to upload your files from anywhere your local computer or just from folder on your server (online or offline)? With me, all IMCE does is create a button in my dialog window that says 'browse server'. That would be ok for me as builder of the site but the idea is to have users create their blog entries and be able to insert pictures via the wysiwyg editor from folders on their hard drive.

Comment: You should have an upload button in the IMCE toolbar. Each user then can upload assets to whatever directories IMCE is configured for (see /admin/config/media/imce). Then the assets can be placed in WYSIWYG content. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using D7 and need simple image upload from computer, CKEditor and [One Click Upload](http://drupal.org/project/ocupload) will be another solution. No need [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) in this case.